# TextBlock.Text and Background issue in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

I am writing Windows Phone 8.1 app, I am binding text to textblock control.

The problem is that, if the amount of text is too long, the whole text is not binding.
the textblock is inside stackpanel, and the background of stackpanel remains black.

See below for details:

For small amount of text:

[image]

For large amount of text:

[image]

see the difference of last stackpanel between two screen shots.

See my XAML code below:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,63,0,0">
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">

  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="White" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5,0,0" Width="480">
    <TextBlock Margin="-305,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" TextAlignment="Left" Width="150" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="Auto"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="DarkBlue" FontSize="22" Height="Auto" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="-5,19,0,12" Width="450" TextAlignment="Left"/>
  </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Hi, first please try to avoid using negative margin, plus can you provide proper screenshot (change your data if needed) but it will be way more understandable than the paint edit. Thanks

Comment: @Aymeric I read somewhere that, its limited to 2048 px. That is the matter. Is it so?

Comment: @Aymeric by the way, I can't give it, the second screen shot is describing that, there is too much text, therefore the background property and text is cutting off.

Comment: @Aymeric first screent shot is just one line statement. It works successfully.

Comment: @NiteshKothari What happens if you take that code out of that Grid you have.. I think your Top Grid row definitions is messing with your ScrollViewer.  The Textblock does have a max length.  Though I don't call what it is.  It is pretty high though.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware If I take that code out of grid, result remains same. And by the way, is row definition necessary? Thanks. please suggest me.

Comment: This is difficult to reproduce. Could you provide a sample repo or something that we can work from?

Comment: @DecadeMoon what you want bro? I am not getting any kind of error. Its working for small amount of text, and cutting off text for large data. thanks!!